# Why doesn't this thread pool execute HTTP requests simultaneously?

Tags: java, http, threadpool, executorservice, resttemplate

I wrote a few lines of code which will send 50 HTTP GET requests to a service running on my machine. The service will always `sleep 1` second and return a HTTP status code 200 with an empty body. As expected the code runs for about 50 seconds.

To speed things up a little I tried to create an `ExecutorService` with 4 threads so I could always send 4 requests at the same time to my service. I expected the code to run for about 13 seconds.

```java
final List<String> urls = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    urls.add("http://localhost:5000/test/" + i);

final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

final List<Callable<String>> tasks = urls
        .stream()
        .map(u -> (Callable<String>) () -> {
            System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now() + " - " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": " + u);
            return restTemplate.getForObject(u, String.class);
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());

final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
try {
    final List<Future<String>> futures = executorService.invokeAll(tasks);

    final List<String> results = futures.stream().map(f -> {
        try {
            return f.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(results);
} finally {
    executorService.shutdown();
    executorService.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

final long elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
System.out.println("Took " + elapsed + " ms...");
```

But - if you look at the seconds of the debug output - it seems like the first 4 requests are executed simultaneously but all other request are executed one after another:

```
2018-10-21T17:42:16.160 - pool-1-thread-3: http://localhost:5000/test/2
2018-10-21T17:42:16.160 - pool-1-thread-1: http://localhost:5000/test/0
2018-10-21T17:42:16.160 - pool-1-thread-2: http://localhost:5000/test/1
2018-10-21T17:42:16.159 - pool-1-thread-4: http://localhost:5000/test/3
2018-10-21T17:42:17.233 - pool-1-thread-3: http://localhost:5000/test/4
2018-10-21T17:42:18.232 - pool-1-thread-2: http://localhost:5000/test/5
2018-10-21T17:42:19.237 - pool-1-thread-4: http://localhost:5000/test/6
2018-10-21T17:42:20.241 - pool-1-thread-1: http://localhost:5000/test/7
...
Took 50310 ms...
```

So for debugging purposes I changed the HTTP request to a `sleep` call:

```java
// return restTemplate.getForObject(u, String.class);
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
return "";
```

And now the code works as expected:

```
...
Took 13068 ms...
```

So my question is why does the code with the sleep call work as expected and the code with the HTTP request doesn't? And how can I get it to behave in the way I expected?

Comment: Probably because the first four threads are busy, so there's no parallelism after that.  "sleep(1)" is basically no time at all, so it finishes immediately.  Your processing evidently takes much longer than a "sleep(1)".

Comment: @markspace There is no additional processing and the sleep(1) really referes to a second: `plackup -e 'sub { sleep 1; return [200, ["Content-Type" => "text/plain"], [""]] }'`

Comment: How many threads are there at the other end?

Comment: I guess the problem is server logic (your bussines service).
It look like your server don't serve mutiple request in the same time.
Can u put your server code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the information, I can see this is the most probable root cause:

> The requests you make are done in parallel but the **HTTP server** which fulfils these request *handles 1 request at a time*.

So when you start making requests, the `executor service fires up the requests concurrently`,  thus you get the first 4 at same time.

But the **HTTP server** can **respond** to requests **one at a time** i.e. after 1 second each.

Now when 1st request is fulfilled the executor service picks another request and fires it and this goes on till last request.

4 request are blocked at HTTP server at a time, which are being **served serially** one after the other.

To get a `Proof of Concept` of this theory what you can do is use a messaging service (queue) which can receive concurrently from 4 channels an test. That should reduce the time.